# Cannot connect to Apple file servers after upgrading to 10.8

Tags: finder, macos, afp

Since I can't find thousands of other users reporting this I'm thinking it's got to be something wrong with my system, but after I updated to Mountain Lion I can't connect to Apple file servers anymore.

Not even a Drobo FS.

The servers still show up in my sidebar but they never successfully connect.

I tried creating a new user and connecting from that one, but still had the same problem.

The OSX servers are running 10.6 & 10.7.

Really? No one else is having this problem?

Comment: Can you post any error messages you see in Console.app. Also, try connecting directly by hitting command-K in Finder and entering the server address manually (don't forget the afp:// prefix).

Comment: No problems connecting to AFP service of Mac OS X Server 10.5.8.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that obsolete iDisk settings in OSX 10.8 may prevent you to connect to a file server.

You need to run those commands in Terminal

```
defaults delete -g iToolsMember
defaults delete -g iToolsMemberDomain
```

to get rid of those settings.

Source: http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/odd-afp-and-smb-connection-problem-caused-by-idisk-going-away/